# Bash: Find word in string

Tags: bash

Is there any way to accomplish this **without** using external programs like `sed`, `grep`, `awk` or the `[[ ]]` construct and without using nested loops?

Basically, I would like to loop over the provided arguments(words) and check whether it's in the string.

By word, I mean actual tokens (IFS separated strings).

So, find word3 in string `word1 word2 word3 word4`

The only crappy solution I could come up with is:

```bash
string="word1 word2 word3 word4"

# attempt to remove diff combos of
# space + word
for i in $@; do
    [ "${string/ $i / }" == "$string" ] &&
    [ "${string/#$i / }" == "$string" ] &&
    [ "${string/% $i/ }" == "$string" ] &&
    echo "$i not found" && continue


    # if found, actually remove
    # again attempting diff combos
    string="${string/ $i / }"
    string="${string/#$i / }"
    string="${string/% $i/ }"
done

echo "$string"
```

This should give:

```bash
~$ ./script word1 word3 word5

word5 not found
word2 word4
```

Comment: You could instead replace the spaces with pipes "|" and run it as a grep regex: grep -E -o 'word1|word2|word3' test.txt. That will give you words that are found, anyway.

Comment: Read the first sentence again..

Comment: Whelp, I can't read. I missed the first sentence entirely and started at "Basically". Sorry about that. I'll think about it a bit. Is there a particular reason you can't use those, or python/perl/etc?

Comment: In the case of `case` (lol) I'd still have to test against different combos. I didn't manage to make it look any cleaner then what I already  have. :/

Comment: @goodguy5 I just wanted to see whether it's possible.

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind precluding `[[ ]]`?

Comment: @Component10 I guess curiosity. Also, it's a bashism.

Answer (score 2):

Modern Bash

```
$ a="qqq www eee rrr"
$ eval typeset -A t=( $(printf '[%s]=1 ' $a) )

$ w=www
$ [ "${t[$w]}" ] && echo yes || echo no
yes
     
$ w=oops
$ [ "${t[$w]}" ] && echo yes || echo no
no
```

Even though there is no apparent loop here, there is necessarilly one internally (the loading of the t[] array), then looking for a word is done by hashing.

There is no fork/exec since printf is a builtin here, when t[] is not needed anymore, unset it.

This answer is late :) I give it for the record.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the traditional `expr` syntax. e.g. `expr $string : $regex`. For example, using your input (and reformatting slightly), you could do:

```
#!/bin/bash --norc

string="word1 word2 word3 word4"

for i in $@; do

    if [ $(expr "$string" : ".*$i.*") -gt 0 ]; then
        printf "'%s' found in '%s'\n" "$i" "$string"
    else
        printf "'%s' NOT found in '%s'\n" "$i" "$string"    
    fi

done
```

**Output**

```
$ bash srchwordexpr.sh word1 word3 word5
'word1' found in 'word1 word2 word3 word4'
'word3' found in 'word1 word2 word3 word4'
'word5' NOT found in 'word1 word2 word3 word4'
```

`expr` is not one of your excluded tools, whether you consider it to belong in that group, let me know.

You can also use a simple substring removal with the same results:

```
if [ "$string" != "${string/$i}" ]; then
```

Comment: I was hoping for a solution without use of external commands.

Comment: Look at my last edit `if [ "$string" != "${string/$i}" ]; then`

Comment: Oh, didn't notice that. That's not gonna work here. Notice I'm using the same thing, but I'm looking for words, not substrings. That would match both `word1` and `word123`

Comment: Don't forget to double-quote `$@` i.e. `"$@"`.

Comment: @zagortenay333 As for matching "words" then just substring to include a space? Or does that not work how I think it does?

Comment: @goodguy5 The issue is that there can be a space in front but not after, or vice versa, or a space on both ends That's why my solution looks so fugly.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

string="word1 word2 word3 word4"

# Usage: inarray "$value" "${array[@]}"
inarray() { local n=$1 h; shift; for h; do [ "$n" == "$h" ] && return; done; return 1; }

read -ra arr <<< "$string"

for arg; do
    if inarray "$arg" "${arr[@]}"; then
        printf '%s FOUND in "%s"\n' "$arg" "$string"
    else
        printf '%s NOT FOUND in "%s"\n' "$arg" "$string"
    fi
done
```

**Usage example:**
(*Script name is `sof`*)

```
./sof word1 wor word3 "word4 "
word1 FOUND in "word1 word2 word3 word4"
wor NOT FOUND in "word1 word2 word3 word4"
word3 FOUND in "word1 word2 word3 word4"
word4  NOT FOUND in "word1 word2 word3 word4"
```

**EDIT**
I noticed that the OP requested to not use nested loops, which this answer does.
Therefore it does not answers the question.I'll leave the answer here in case that someone will benefit from it in the future, unless I'll be requested to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Use an intermediate array:

```
#!/bin/bash
string="word1 word2 word3 word4"
array=($string)
for i in "$@"; do
    found=false
    for j in "${!array[@]}"; do
        if [[ $i == ${array[$j]} ]]; then
            unset array[$j]
            found=true
            break
        fi
    done
    "$found" || echo "$i not found" >&2
done
echo "${array[@]}"
```

The result is exactly what you were asking for:

```
$ ./script word1 word3 word5
word5 not found
word2 word4
```